# Change text based on toggle values in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, text, toggle, swiftui, swift5

I have created a View with Text, Image and Navigation Button in SwiftUI.When navigation button is pressed it will navigate to another view which contains Toggle.When I change the Toggle Value , I also want to change the Text value in the previous View.

Value is getting updated when changing the toggle but didn't reflected when accessed in previous View.

//BluetoothView.swift

```
struct BluetoothView: View {
    @ObjectBinding var bluetooth = Settings()

    var body: some View {
        return NavigationButton(destination: ToggleBluetoothView()) {
            HStack() {
                Image("default")
                    .resizable()
                    .cornerRadius(12)
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    .clipped()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                Text("Bluetooth")
                    .color(.blue)
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                Text(bluetooth.isBluetoothOn ? "On" : "Off")
                    .color(.gray)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 40, alignment: .trailing)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//ToggleBluetoothView.swift

```
struct ToggleBluetoothView: View {
    @ObjectBinding var bluetooth = Settings()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("ENABLE TO CONNECT WITH NEARBY DEVICES")) {
                Toggle(isOn: $bluetooth.isBluetoothOn) {
                    Text("Bluetooth")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

//Settings.swift

```
class Settings: BindableObject {

        var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

       var isBluetoothOn = false { didSet { update() } }

        func update() {
            didChange.send(())
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating Settings separately in each view. Both views need to be seeing the same Settings object:

Change the following:

```swift
NavigationButton(destination: ToggleBluetoothView(bluetooth: bluetooth)) { ... }
```

and remove the initial value in ToggleBluetoothView:

```swift
struct ToggleBluetoothView: View {
    @ObjectBinding var bluetooth: Settings

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("ENABLE TO CONNECT WITH NEARBY DEVICES")) {
                Toggle(isOn: $bluetooth.isBluetoothOn) {
                    Text("Bluetooth")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you are going to pass around your **@BindableObject** around many views, you may consider using **@EnvironmentObject** instead. Check WWDC session 226 (Data Flow Through SwiftUI).